# How to handle bad logon when copying file from network drive

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that copies a file from a network drive to the desktop.

If I were manually doing this, I occasionally get prompted for credentials when I attempt to access the network drive.

When the batch script runs into this situation, it gives me a "Bad username/password" error. I would like to catch the error (kind of like try-catch in other languages, is there an equivalent in a batch script?) and logon to the domain.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some excerpts from a script I'm working with. These excerpts address some issues that are almost identical to your problem.

```
del dela delb /f /q 2>nul 1>nul
echo |net use %letter%: "\\%servername%\%sharename%" /persistent:YES 2>delb 1>dela
    REM this part is the cool part: the "echo |" passes "" to the net use in case it prompts for username/password.
    REM When the net use gets that input on the username prompt, it returns "user canceled the action" and we
    REM capture that later on.
findstr /r /i /c:"successfully" dela 1>nul 2>nul
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (
    echo Success: %letter%: as \\%servername%\%sharename%
) else (
    echo Failed: %letter%: as \\%servername%\%sharename%.

    REM possible errors:
    REM 1. syserr 55: "no longer available" = folder doesn't exist.     ACTIONS: inform user, continue
    REM 2.      1223: "canceled" = wrong password/username.             ACTIONS: ask for creds, ask to re-run script.
    REM 3. syserr  3: "cannot find the path specified" = bad sharename. ACTIONS: inform user, continue
    REM 4. syserr 85: "already in use" = didn't remove old drive maps.  ACTIONS: warn user, continue
    ::type delb
    ::echo above is delb.
    set thisErr=
    findstr /r /i /c:"cannot find the path specified" delb 1>nul 2>nul
    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] set thisErr=notexists
    findstr /r /i /c:"longer" delb 1>nul 2>nul
    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] set thisErr=nolongeravailable
    findstr /r /i /c:"canceled" delb 1>nul 2>nul
    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] set thisErr=wrongcreds
    findstr /r /i /c:"already in use" delb 1>nul 2>nul
    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] set thisErr=alreadyused
    if [%thisErr%]==[wrongcreds] (
        echo Cannot connect to the server due to incorrect credentials...
        if defined TRUE (
            set /p uname=Enter the username to connect to '%servername%': 
            REM echo !uname!
            cmdkey /add:%servername% /u:!uname! /p
            REM cmdkey /add:%servername% /user:%username% /pass:%password%
        ) else (
            cmdkey /add:%servername% /u:%username% /p:%password%
        )
        ::echo Break the script and try again, now that the password is added to Windows Credential vault.
        ::pause
        echo Restarting script...
        goto :restartPoint
        exit /b
    )
    if [!thisErr!]==[nolongeravailable] (
        echo This resource no longer exists. Skipping this drive.
    )
    if [!thisErr!]==[notexists] (
        echo This resource does not exist. Skipping this drive.
    )
    if [!thisErr!]==[alreadyused] (
        echo This drive letter is already in use. Skipping this drive.
    )
)
```

)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that this originally came from a larger loop of some sort. The `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command might affect how the % and ! variable name wrappers work. Generally, the ! wrappers are for variables generated and used inside a for/do loop. It's confusing, but tweak those until you get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Caution: `ECHO |...` will pass "ECHO is on/off." Use `ECHO.|...` instead.

Comment: @LS_dev, that's technically true, but since the command I show pipes it directly to a username prompt, it still acts the same in this instance and doesn't really matter.